# WebRTC - Receive video from another peer using an offer from an audio-only stream

Tags: html, webrtc

Is is possible to receive both video and audio from another peer if the peer who called `createOffer()` only allowed audio when requested via `getUserMedia()`?

Explanation by scenario:

1. Alice connects to a signalling server, and when `getUserMedia()` is called, chooses to share **both** video and audio.
2. Bob connects to the signalling server, and when `getUserMedia()` is called, **only** shares audio.
3. As Bob is the last to party, Bob creates the peer connection offer via `RTCPeerConnection.createOffer()`. He shares his `localDescription` which contains SDP data that does not mention video.
4. The resultant connection is audio-only as the SDP data only contained audio-related information.

Can an offer be created that asks to receive video data without sharing it?

Comment: yes, you can ask for video+audio while providing only audio, even without providing any media from your side. it all comes down to what you do with `setStream` on your `PeerConnection`,

Comment: Cheers, I managed to get it to work (see answer).

Comment: I handy trick may be to  use a dummy video stream when getUserMedia has not video constraint. So, if later this peer wants to share video, all you need to do is call replaceTrack API and no re-negotiation will be needed. also this will simply your clients 
remote stream handling by assuming video will be always shared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the key was in the creation of the offer.

### Referring to the Specification

The [WebRTC 1.0 specification](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions) says:

> **4.2.5 Offer/Answer Options**
>
> These dictionaries describe the options that can be used to control the offer/answer creation process.
>
> ```
> dictionary RTCOfferOptions {
>     long    offerToReceiveVideo;
>     long    offerToReceiveAudio;
>     boolean voiceActivityDetection = true;
>     boolean iceRestart = false;
> };
> ```

In the case of video:

> ```
> offerToReceiveVideo of type long
> ```
>
> In some cases, an RTCPeerConnection may wish to receive video but not send any video. The RTCPeerConnection needs to know if it should signal to the remote side whether it wishes to receive video or not. This option allows an application to indicate its preferences for the number of video streams to receive when creating an offer.

### Solution

[`RTCPeerConnection.createOffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#createOffer) can take `MediaConstraints` as an optional third parameter.

The example I found was from the [WebRTC for Beginners](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-beginners.html) article:

> **Creating Offer SDP**
>
> ```
> peerConnection.createOffer(function (sessionDescription) {
>     peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
>
>     // POST-Offer-SDP-For-Other-Peer(sessionDescription.sdp, sessionDescription.type);
>
> }, function(error) {
>     alert(error);
> }, { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } });
> ```

These `MediaContraints` can also be used with `createAnswer()`.

Comment: Note that the syntax in the example is different from the spec, but is needed to work with Google Chrome (note the difference in case; 'O' vs. 'o' in offerToReceiveVideo, and the mandatory/optional language which has been dropped from the spec). While Firefox supports both new and old syntax, Chrome currently chokes on the new syntax, so until Chrome updates, the old syntax is the most compatible.

Comment: Awesome! This was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Life safer. Should be rated "Best answer".

Comment: I'm trying to receive Video and Audio, but not send anything. I added the third parameter with the mandatory key and its values to my offer. However, nothing works unless I actively add my localstream using .addStream() meaning it's forcing me to send video regardless or not. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Bob's offer will contain audio, but alice will also share her video.

When Bob later wishes to add (video) streams he calls `RtcPeerConnection.addStream()` and a (re-)negotiation is needed (see `negotiationneeded` event). This will allow Bob to add different (additional video) or additional streams at any time he wishes. You just have to make sure that on the offer/answer will be exchanged correctly (e.g. at negotiationneeded event).

I wrote a (dart based) webrtc library that might help you to see how it works. See [Sender](https://github.com/roberthartung/webrtc_utils/blob/master/lib/src/client/peer.dart#L95) and [Receiver](https://github.com/roberthartung/webrtc_utils/blob/master/lib/src/client/peer.dart#L158)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to resolve the issue by adding a third parameter in `createOffer()` with an `offerToReceiveVideo` option.